# how to visualize cross-attention maps for checking text-image alignment well?

Tags: pytorch, visualization, transformer-model, attention-model, self-attention

I was wondering how to visualize cross-attention map of image features a model is looking at given a text query (e.g. sentence).
There are some amazing explainable tools ilke Class Activationi Maps, but they are almost needed 'class' or CNN model (of course, there is vit-attention map too, but for classification problem). [pytorch-grad-cam](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam), [vit-attention map with classes](https://www.kaggle.com/code/piantic/vision-transformer-vit-visualize-attention-map/notebook)
But I can't count how many classes words have. This is because each sentence is made up of different words.
How can I visualize a cross-attention encoder output?

PLZ help me.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.